# Swift convert a String to an enum Type

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I just created following code as an example, i'm looking for a way to get from a textfield.text to a value of type Month and assign it to a let bmonth:

```
enum Month {
    case January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December
}

struct BirthDay {
    let day: Int
    let month: Month
    let year: Int

    func calculateWesternZodiac() {
        // some long code
    }

    func calculateVedicZodiac() {
        // some long code
    }
}

// Hardcoding the values

let myBirthday = BirthDay(day: 02, month: .February, year: 1980)

// values from input textField

let bday = Int(dayTextField.text)
let bmonth = Month(monthTextField.text) // I'm looking for the correct way  of doing this ! 
let byear = Int(yearTextField.text)

let yourBirthday = BirthDay(day: bday, month: bmonth, year: byear)
```

anybody here knows how to do this ?

Comment: See the section on enumeration raw values in the Swift book

Comment: Thank you, i figured it out :)